# Ant build with .so files

Tags: java, android, ant, android-ndk

I'm working on a  project which contains over >65k methods, i have followed the [Dex65536](https://github.com/mmin18/Dex65536) process to build the project

In my project it contains some **.so** files to do **database** encryption in my project.when apply **ant** task with this custom rule i got an error like

```
Warning:No implementation found for native 
Error: Lcom.......java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:
```

how can i solve this issue and how do i specify the **.so** files in **custom_rules.xml** file.

please advice me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please show the `pom.xml` code for the same

Comment: I dont have pom.xml,i am using only custom_rule.xml.you can find the same file in https://github.com/mmin18/Dex65536

Comment: copy your `.so` file in libs directory in you android project and then run compile

Comment: i do the same but no result.i have done sample project with same .so files,its working perfectly.but when i am integrate into my project got an error.please read the question once agian.because my project contains over 65k+ methods.its not possible to run project by eclips.we have to use ant build or some other multidexapp.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your apk contians the .so inside the armeabi folder, then you don't need to look at the ant build process.

The error you are receiving is caused by either the .so failing to load or by having your functions names wrongly exported /imported.

Are you certain of the following :

- there is a .so library inside your armeabi & armeabi-v7a folders (you will need the .so in both folders, because some Android versions look in different folders) - decompress the apk to be 100% sure
- the .so library is compiled for the correct architecture of the target device
- inside your java code you call System.loadLibrary prior to any native code
- the exported functions from your native code respects the correct naming :

for the Java method

```
int com.sample.NativeBridge.GetInt()
```

you will need to have exported a pair c method

`JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_sample_NativeBridge_GetInt(JNIEnv env , jclass this)`

Considering you have a huge amount of methods, is it possible for the original container class to be splitted into multiple classes, a point at which the C functions names don't match the correct naming convention ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.i solve the issue my self.my apk contain the .so files in armeabi & armeabi-v7a folders,but my mistake is am not loading the system.loadlib in proper-way.

Comment: What do you mean you didn't use System.loadLibrary in proper way ? library name passed was incorrect ?